# How to compute a percentage increase/decrease multiplier in python without if statements

Tags: python

I have a scenario in which the user enter a positive, 0, or negative value which represents a percentage increase, no change, or percentage decrease, respectively. Example: 2.5 means "increase by 2.5%",  -3 means "decrease by 3%". Let's call this user entered number U.

I need to apply U to some number, X, in python... that is, apply the percentage increase/decrease specified in U to X to come up with the possibly altered value for X.

I can see one way to do this is by examining U and come up with a multiplier that can be multiplied by X, such as

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1
elif U > 0:
   multiplier = U/100.0 + 1
else:
   multiplier = (100 - (U * -1.0))/100.0
```

And then I can arrive at the new value of X with:  X = X * multiplier.

Finally, the challenging part: *Is there a way to come up with a multiplier without using multiple if statements as I've done above?*

The reason I ask is because I'm actually having to write a snippet of python code that has to be contained in one line (it is is going to be dynamically executed with exec()) and thus I can't have blocks.

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!
Michael

Comment: instead of getting a multiplier why not get something to add?  eg (U/100) *X then add it to X

Comment: Executing *user input* as part of an expression with `exec` is a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed, in general. In my case, the "user input" is actually a control file that I create myself.. not exposed to a real user in any way.. so it should be "safe" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use the distributive property of division:

**`multiplier = 1 + U/100.0`**

**This is actually what your code does**. You just separated three branches of a `if` that did exactly the same. Let's do some easy math step-by-step from your original code:

---

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1
elif U > 0:
   multiplier = U/100.0 + 1
else:
   multiplier = (100 - (U * -1.0))/100.0
```

---

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1 + 0                 #sum 0 for convenience
elif U > 0:
   multiplier = 1 + U/100.0           #swap order of addition
else:
   multiplier = (100 + U)) / 100.0    #multiplying by -1 is just changing the sign
```

---

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1 + U/100.0    # since U is 0 in this branch, U/100.0 == 0
elif U > 0:
   multiplier = 1 + U/100.0
else:
   multiplier = 1 + U/100.0    # distributive property of division
```

---

Since the executed code is the same for the three branches, there's no point having a `if`:

```
multiplier = 1 + U/100.0
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't think the zero case would work, but it does.  I think I initially had parens in the wrong spot, changing the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

if and else can actually be used in expressions on one line: `x = a if b else c`.
You can't use elif, though, so you'll have to first refactor your code so it doesn't use them:

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1
else:
    if U > 0:
       multiplier = U/100.0 + 1
    else:
       multiplier = (100 - (U * -1.0))/100.0
```

This reduces to

```
if U == 0:
   multiplier = 1
else:
   multiplier = U/100.0 + 1 if U > 0 else (100 - (U * -1.0))/100.0
```

Which reduces to

```
multiplier = 1 if U == 0 else (U/100.0 + 1 if U > 0 else (100 - (U * -1.0))/100.0)
```

Comment: Uhm, ok. Why not just `multiplier = 1 + U / 100.0`?

Comment: +1, regardless of the actual minutiae of the original mathematics, this answer holds in the general case.

Comment: Thanks, I like the creative use of the "conditional expressions" in Python. It turns out I don't need it for this particular problem but it's good to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer is technically completely correct, but your code can be simplified a whole lot just from a math standpoint.

You don't need to be performing if-then-else checks on this mathematical operation.
Consider the input of "-3": In your code, this will go into the third block, evaluate as (100 - (-3 * -1.0)) / 100.0 = (100 - 3.0) / 100.0 = 0.97.

This is equivalent to the value U going into the second block, evaluated as (-3 / 100.0) + 1 = -0.03 + 1 = 0.97.

Now consider the input of 0: No matter which block it goes in to, the "multiplier" value will come out as 1.

So just have your code be:

```
multiplier = 1 + (U / 100.0)
```

and you'll be set.